# Read string from a file, replace it, store it in a new file. (Python 3.x)

Tags: python

Create a Mad Libs program that reads in text files and lets the user add their own text anywhere the word ADJECTIVE, NOUN, ADVERB, or VERB appears in the text file. For example, a text file may look like this:

> The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
>   unaffected by these events.

The program would find these occurrences and prompt the user to replace them.

```
Enter an adjective:
silly
Enter a noun:
chandelier
Enter a verb:
screamed
Enter a noun:
pickup truck
```

The following text file would then be created:

> The silly panda walked to the chandelier and then screamed. A nearby pickup truck was unaffected by these events.

The results should be printed to the screen and saved to a new text file.

My Code:

```
import os

InputFile = open('FileOne.txt','r')
InputContent = InputFile.read()
InputFile.close()

outputFile = open('FileTwo.txt','w')
convert = InputContent
for word in ['NOUN', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB']:
    if word in InputContent:
        convert = convert.replace(word, input('Enter %s: ' %word))

outputFile.write(convert)
outputFile.close()
```

The contents of my FileOne are : NOUN is a ADJECTIVE person. Suddenly NOUN VERB. NOUN is now dead.

When I run the code :

```
Enter NOUN: Dave
Enter ADJECTIVE: lovely
Enter VERB: screamed.
```

It creates the output textfile FileTwo, but it's empty.

The output file should contain

> Dave is a lovely person. Suddenly Dave screamed. Dave is now dead.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : Changed the code. It works now. Thank you very much for your help :D

Comment: `convert` is different from `Convert`.

Comment: You've set `convert` with a lower-case 'c' to an empty string. Then you set 'Convert' with an upper-case 'c' in the loop.

Comment: I'll change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your variable convert that you are trying to overwrite is an empty string. So when you go to put the output in the second file you are placing literally nothing in there.

If instead you take convert and set it equal to InputContent, then after each replacement you set convert equal to Convert then it works great:

```
import os

InputFile = open('FileOne.txt','r')
InputContent = InputFile.read()
InputFile.close()

outputFile = open('FileTwo.txt','w')
convert = InputContent
for word in ['NOUN', 'ADJECTIVE', 'VERB']:
    if word in InputContent:
        Convert = convert.replace(word, input('Enter %s: ' %word))
        convert = Convert
outputFile.write(Convert)
outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember to accept an answer to close the thread ;)

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew about that. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Trying a simplified version of your code in a python interpreter shows the error very clearly

```
>>>convert = ''
>>>convert.replace('abc', '123')
''
```

You're taking the empty string '' and replacing NOUN (which doesn't exist) with Dave, the result of which is still an empty string.

You are then writing the empty string to FileTwo.txt

The solution would be to call replace() on InputContent

A simple example being

```
>>>InputContent = 'Hello NOUN, my name is NOUN'
>>>InputContent.replace('NOUN', 'Dave')
'Hello Dave, my name is Dave'
```

Now you see that replace() replaces **all instances** of your search term (in this case NOUN)

Solving this new problem will be left as an exercise for you